# Terraform Count Functionality Using IF / OR

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'd like to set the count function for a terraform resource to be dependent on the value of a variable.

In plain English I would like the following...

IF
var.domain_name_suffix is equal to "all" OR "GW",
Set Count to 1.

ELSE
Set count to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [reading the](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/conditionals) [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/operators).

```
count = var.domain_name_suffix == "all" || var.domain_name_suffix == "GW" ? 1 : 0
```